# The right way to sort SPL collections in PHP

Tags: php, spl

Is there any uniform and efficient way to sort [SPL collections](http://php.net/manual/en/spl.datastructures.php) like `SplFixedArray`, `SplDoublyLinkedList` and etc?

Standard functions like `usort` doesn't work at all, because they are awaiting that the first argument has array type.

Comment: I think it would be the normal iterator methods: http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayiterator.php and more generally http://php.net/manual/en/spl.iterators.php

Comment: How can I use those iterators to sort, for example, `SplFixedArray`? Take into account, I need to change it, not traverse it or recreate one (because it is obviously not efficient way).